# Expo eas build android aap error: [stderr] npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

Tags: android, npm, expo, eas

I'm facing an error while using eas in expo to build android .aab bundle.

The expo app is running correctly on expo with all dependencies installed. But, when executing:
`eas build -p android`

The expo shows an error:

```
Running "npm install" in the root dir of your repository 
[stderr] npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
[stderr] npm ERR!
[stderr] ERESOLVE could not resolve
[stderr] npm ERR! 
[stderr] npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-elements@3.4.2
[stderr] npm ERR! Found: react-native-safe-area-context@4.4.1
[stderr] npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context
[stderr] npm
[stderr] ERR!   react-native-safe-area-context@"4.4.1" from the root project
[stderr] npm ERR!   peer react-native-safe-area-context@">= 3.0.0" from @react-navigation/elements@1.3.6
[stderr] npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/elements
[stderr] npm ERR!     @react-navigation/elements@"^1.3.6" from @react-navigation/stack@6.3.4
[stderr] npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
[stderr] npm ERR!       @react-navigation/stack@"^6.3.4" from the root project
[stderr] npm ERR!   2 more (@react-navigation/stack, @rneui/base)
[stderr] npm ERR! 
[stderr] npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
[stderr] npm ERR! peer react-native-safe-area-context@"^3.1.9" from react-native-elements@3.4.2
[stderr] npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-elements
[stderr] npm ERR!   react-native-elements@"^3.4.2" from the root project
[stderr] npm ERR! 
[stderr] npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native-safe-area-context@3.4.1
[stderr] npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context
[stderr] npm
[stderr] ERR!   peer react-native-safe-area-context@"^3.1.9" from react-native-elements@3.4.2
[stderr] npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-elements
[stderr] npm ERR!     react-native-elements@"^3.4.2" from the root project
[stderr] npm ERR! 
[stderr] npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
[stderr] npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
[stderr] npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
[stderr] npm ERR! 
[stderr] npm ERR! See /home/expo/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
[stderr] 
[stderr] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[stderr] npm ERR!     /home/expo/.npm/_logs/2022-12-17T19_35_38_310Z-debug-0.log
npm exited with non-zero code: 1
```

I've tried to install legacy-peer-deps (`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`). I also tried to put as a dependency (`"legacy-peer-deps":"^7.24.2"`) on package.json.

Any further suggestion? Thank you in advance.